# Pictures are deleted after a certain time

Tags: image, uv-image-editor

Sometimes, depending on blenders mood I guess, some images are deleted after a while... without the user doing anything, not even touching blender's interface.

People have already suggested to save during the process, but sometimes I just wish to try things out in the image editor and make a collection of availbale images.

1. Set render mode to Cycles.
2. Create a plane, go into edit mode and unwrap.
3. Go to the image editor, create a new image, call it '1' (default resolution 1024), don't draw anything yet.
4. Do this five times, so the images are named 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5 .
5. Create another image and name it 'collection'.
6. Add a last image with a resolution of 128 by 128 and call it 'logo' (we will use this as a brush).
7. Now draw the corresponding number on each image (for simplicity's sake), so draw a number 1 in image number 1, 2 in image number 2 etc.
8. Draw a figure in the image called 'logo' (adjust the resolution of the brush).
9. Now go to the image called 'collection' and go to the texture tab (on the right) for brush settings and select new image 'logo'. We will use this as a brush to draw into the image 'collection'.
10. Draw something in this image.
11. Now go to the node editor, create an image input node, connect it to the shader colour input.
12. Create input, texture coordinate node and route uv out to the input of the image texture node, select an image from the texture node dropdown list.

After a while, some images are simply erased from memory.

If someone can give me a reasonable explanation as to why this happens, I would be thankful and grateful.

This happens both in blender 2.7 and 2.8

Comment: By 'after a certain time' do you mean after closing and re-opening the file?

Comment: How much time has elapsed and have you saved the initial images to disk or are you floating them in your ram only? What are your settings for auto file save increments?

Comment: No after closing and re-opening 
I am trying to replicate this but it's not so easy ..sometimes it happens after 5 minutes , sometimes it takes 30 minutes.
I set it up as described above and then leave blender alone ..not even touching the pc